# Location Consistency across my iOS application

Tags: ios

I am working on location-based Application.

Assume I have ViewController 1(RootVC) -> MountainView is current Location.
Now User navigated to another ViewController 2 from ViewController 1 and there is an option to change location in ViewController 2 if the user changes the location in ViewController 2 and move back to ViewController it should be updated with new location request the API if there is no location change in ViewController 2 it should not do the API call again. Same case if the user navigated to ViewController 3 from ViewController 2 if there is a change in location from ViewController 3 it should reflect in VC2 and VC1.

I thought of doing with delegates but the problem is it will call instantly when we change location in VC2 it will call VC1 delegate and load the page, but I want to load the page only when the user navigates to VC1. Same happens with Notification or observer pattern also.

Any design pattern I can use and achieve this throughout the App.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `viewDidAppear(){}` delegate method and some flags to acquire desired effect. Use delegate pattern to update the flags and on viewDidAppear() check if the flag has changed and update your viewController accordingly.

Comment: I don't want use flags is there any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current location in a central place; you could use UserDefaults or a global variable (even a loose variable with no namespacing at the top of some file, though an instance variable of the app delegate would be better). This constitutes the universal source of truth. Every time a view controller's `viewWillAppear` is called, it updates itself from the central source of truth.

Under some circumstances, `viewWillAppear` will not be a sufficient event (for example, if the user changes the location in a nonfullscreen presented view controller), but in your question it is always push-and-pop on a navigation controller so `viewWillAppear` will work fine.

Comment: But it does not work because I don't need to reload other VCs if there is no change in cental place location.

Comment: The view controller looks to see if the current location is different from what it last updated itself with. If not there is nothing to do.